# What is my error in filtering the pivot table based on the active cell?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

My goal is to filter PivotTable3 based on the active cell selected on the project dashboard sheet. The range for NewCat is set to "U10" but I would like any active cell selected to be the driver for the filter.

NewCat = Worksheets("Project Dash").Range("U10").Value

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("U8:U37")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

Set pt = Worksheets("mPIVOTS").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Project")
NewCat = Worksheets("Project Dash").Range("U10").Value

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but how about changing this line:

```
NewCat = Worksheets("Project Dash").Range("U10").Value
```

To this:

```
NewCat = Target.Value
```